# Generating unique value in java give duplicate

Tags: java

I have a logic to generate unique ID in java as below,

```
private static String generateUniqueNum()
    {
        final int LENGTH = 20;

        final long uniqueNumber = abs(Long.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID().hashCode())) + System.currentTimeMillis() + abs(random.nextLong());

        String value = Long.toString(uniqueNumber).replaceAll("-", "");



        final int endIndex = value.length() <= LENGTH ? value.length() : LENGTH;
        return String.format("MN%s", value.substring(0, endIndex));
    }

     private static Long abs(Long number){
            if(null == number || 0 < number){
                return 0L;
            }
            return Math.abs(number);
        }
```

For the above code I have tested with jmeter with 3000 requests simultaneously and when I checked the result value generted, there are lot of duplicate valus generated. I dont know the reason how the duplicate value generated. Can someone has any idea on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not add anything to an UUID: on its own its guaranteed to be unique. Remove ``System.currentTimeMillis()``. Do not use ``hashCode`` on a UUID: use ``toString``: ``UUID.randomUUID().toString()`` is enough. Additionnally your ``abs`` method is flawed: if number >0 then return 0 else return Math.abs??? are you sure about this algorithm?

Comment: you are still using hashcode on an UUID: this is not going to work... Use: ``UUID.randomUUID().toString()``

Comment: By doing `+ abs(random.nextLong())` you can basically throw everything before that away; your "unique" number will just be a (more or less) random long number.

Answer (score 3):

UUID is unique but uses 128 bits (two longs).

It would be best to use for a database key for instance the String representation. For a less safe `long`:

```
return uuid.getLeastSignificantBits() ^ uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
```

Your clashes stem from hash code being an int (32 bits, a quarter), and combining with other properties will not necessarily make the number more random; even less so.

Comment: ... and above all, there is no guarantee hashCode is distributed evenly... ``public int hashCode() { return 42; }`` is a perfectly valid implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your current approach:

1. `java.util.Random` is not thread-safe. If you have 3000 concurrent requests on different threads to the same `Random` object you may get strange behavior. Try `ThreadLocalRandom` instead.
2. Generated `System.currentTimeMillis()` values will be close together if the 3000 concurrent requests are simultaneous.

Don't over complicate the problem, if you need a unique identifier:

1. Use UUID v4 (`UUID.randomUUID()`) or if you need stronger guarantees UUID v1. There is enough random bits in the UUID to guarantee that [collisions are extremely unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).
2. If you need something more concise maintain a shared counter e.g. database sequence. Simply increment by one each time you want new unique number.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why is your scheme giving significant non-uniqueness?

A: There is a howler of bug!

```
    private static Long abs(Long number){
        if(null == number || 0 < number){
            return 0L;
        }
        return Math.abs(number);
    }
```

If `number` is less than zero, the `0 < number` means that this `abs` method will returning zero as the "absolute" value.

Why does that matter?  Well, your random number generation effectively does this:

```
    long number = yourAbs(random int) + current time in millis + yourAbs(random long)
```

But because of your bug, there is a 50% probability that first term will be zero and a 50% probability that the last term will be zero.

So there is a 25% probablility, your "random" number will be the current time in milliseconds!  Now suppose that you call `generateUniqueNum()` twice in a millisecond .....

Oooops!!!

Note that without this bug, your code would still have a chance of 1 in 2<sup>64</sup> that any pair of numbers generated will be equal.  If you then combine this with a "birthday paradox" analysis, the probability of *any* collisions becomes significant.